# Possible if I grant another user in my AWS account is owner S3 object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an administrator of AWS. I create a S3 bucket, and many sub folder in it. I want grant different permission for another user in my account in this bucket. Example: 
My account ID is 1111-1111-1111, and I create 2 IAM users is alice and bob. I want the folder named is *alice-folder* has owner by alice. All of object which alice created in this folder has owner by her. Same with bob.

I read document in [Controlling ownership](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html) but this said: **The AWS account that uploads an object owns the object, has full control over it, and can grant other users access to it through ACLs.**, not as same as my case.

So, everyone who can talk to me how can I do, it is possible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users do not "own" objects in Amazon S3. The objects are owned by the Account.

If you want to **permit specific IAM Users to use a bucket**, or a portion of a bucket, you can **add policies to an IAM User or IAM Group** to permit them to access the bucket or folder.

Here is an example policy from [User policy examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-policies-s3.html) that permits Alice to access a folder in a bucket:

```json
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:DeleteObjectVersion"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/Alice/*"
      }
   ]
}
```

This policy lets her Put, Get and Delete objects in the folder, which is probably what you want to allow them to do when you say that you want them to 'own' the folder.

If you are assigning such permissions to *many* users, you can instead **create folders based on the name of IAM Users** and then put this policy on an **IAM Group**. Anyone in the IAM Group will be able to use a subfolder with their IAM User name:

```json
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:DeleteObjectVersion"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/${aws:username}/*"
      }
   ]
}
```